# bluetooth earbuds microphone not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I have an mpow M5 bluetooth earbuds. They work flawlessly on my Oneplus 6 android device, using Android 10. But when I connect to my notebook using ubuntu 18.04 and open audio settings it won't recognize my bluetooth earbuds microphone. I tried installing blueman and pairing the earbuds from there but no success either.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and bumping my head, I decided to try out a bluetooth dongle, and manage to get it working. here's what I did:

- I bought an Orico 5.0 bluetooth dongle.
- list usb devices using **lsusb** command. In my case I found this:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

- download xmpow bluetooth BH519A dongle drivers [from this site](https://www.xmpow.com/pages/download). Apparently their dongle uses the same firmware as Orico's.
- install it and reboot your computer, then you are good to go